# dynamic filtering of java object

Tags: java, oop

I have following java object

```
Obj:
----
String id;
List<A>;

A:
--
String A_ID;
String A_PROPERTY;
```

What I am looking for is to be able to search in a given object. ex: search in a list where A.A_ID = 123

I need to dynamically pass

```
A_ID = 123
```

and it would give me

A_Property

I know I could search through a list through iterator, but is there already frameworks out there which lets you do this?

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) is a very nice library for Java 5.

For example:

```
Person me = new Person("Mario", "Fusco", 35);
Person luca = new Person("Luca", "Marrocco", 29);
Person biagio = new Person("Biagio", "Beatrice", 39);
Person celestino = new Person("Celestino", "Bellone", 29);
List<Person> people = asList(me, luca, biagio, celestino);
```

it is possible to filter the ones having more than 30 years applying the following filter:

```
List<Person> over30 = filter(having(on(Person.class).getAge(), greaterThan(30)), people);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/). From their site:

Quaere is an open source, extensible framework that adds a querying syntax reminiscent of SQL to Java applications. Quaere allows you to filter, enumerate and create projections over a number of collections and other queryable resources using a common, expressive syntax.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a framework? how about

```
public String lookupPropertyById(String id)
{
    for (A a : myList)
    {
        if (id.equals(a.id))
            return a.property;
    }
    return null;   // not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hashmap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) if you only search by one property which has the same type for every inputed object. For example, a string.
The object 1 has the string "Obj1" for key and the second object has the string "Test2"
 for key. When you use the get method with the parameter "Obj1", it will return the first object.
P.S. It's really hard to read your "pseudo-code".

Answer (score -1):

Using a hashmap.

```
Map<String,A> map = new HashMap<String,A>();

A a = new A();
a.id = "123";
a.property="Hello there!";

map.put( a.id , a );
```

Later

```
map.get( "123"); // would return the instance of A and then a.property will return "Hello there!"
```

Comment: using a map you'll lose all static typing advantages

Comment: @dfa: For such ambiguous question, I really think mine is a good answer.